# How can I connect to database hosted in VM for Spring development in STS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to do a spring boot project using gradle, but I am in a confusion whether to use net beans or STS to complete my project. I also don't know how to connect to database hosted on a VM.

Comment: Hi rohit! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have a look at the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Try to ask specific questions, with examples of the code that is giving you problems, instead of open-ended questions.

Comment: Hi Rohit, please check out my answer. Accept and up vote if it helps!

Comment: Corrected the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official recommendation for Spring development is [Spring Tool Suite™](https://spring.io/tools/sts). You could also download [Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/home/index.php) and [install STS tool](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-ide) as the plugin to it for the same purpose. Choose either ne of the option.

Next step will to set up the development environment. The recommended way to get started, would be to use `maven` or `gradle` to manage the dependencies for the project. You could also manually download the `.jars`, add them to `classpath` and get started.

To access the database you can use `JDBC`, any ORM tool like `hibernate` or `Spring Data` as per your convinience.

As per the information provided by you, it is clear that you want to set up the `database server` in a VM. The `db server` has to be configured correctlty to allow remote IPs to connect to it.

> Point here is `STS` has no business to do with your `db server`.

STS is just an IDE supporting Spring development. IDE has nothing to do with connecting to your db. You have to write `jdbc`, `orm` or similar code to connect to the db.

There are enough [materials online](https://www.google.com) to learn these tools and technologies.

All the best...:)
I hope my answer helps you!